# Damped harmonic oscillator Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the differential equation for the damped harmonic oscillator doing an ordinary Linear Algebra approach, eigenvalues/vectors, Jordan form and such.

I know it's probably overkill to do it that way, because the DQ isn't very hard exactly, but I just want to do it for fun. Now my question is when do I have to consider the special cases of overdamping, underdamping and critical damping?

My guess is I have to regard this right when I determine the eigenvalues and simply assume I have a double solution, two different eigenvalues or complex eigenvalues. I'm just curious if there is a most general approach that will give me all 3 solutions with minor refinements in the end, like solving it for complex values and then only taking the real part for instance.

That said, I solved the overdamping case. Just tried underdamping and I'm unable to find the eigenvectors for the complex eigenvalues, it's just too hard to find these vectors without using wolframalpha (and I can't use it in exams), any tips on finding the eigenvectors?

I mean I'm fairly certain I have to consider the special cases right at the beginning, I'm simply missing linear independence I think. Still, maybe some of you have something insightful to share. What would you say is generally the best way to approach such equations (especially for the harmonic oscillator)? Should I forget about these matrices and just try a complex approach?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R32xJ.jpg

> pic related

Comment: Although the picture is clear enough to read, please write down the question and your work so that your question becomes self-contained.

Comment: that's just a waste of time

Comment: does nobody know how to properly derive the solutions for the critically damped b) and underdamped c) harmonic oscillator?
do I just assume my new eigenvalues are both -gamma for b) and complex for c) and then go from there?
if I try that, however, I'm unable to find the corresponding eigenvectors with the new (A-lambda*I)-matrix

Comment: @axin No one wants to waste their time answering your question if you're not willing to waste your time asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is a little long comment rather than a complete answer.

To solve damped harmonic oscillator $\ddot{x} + 2\lambda \dot{x} + \omega_0^2 = 0$, set $p = \dot{x}$ and $q = x$. Then the equation is written by equations
$$\begin{align*}
\dot{p} &= -2\lambda p - \omega_0^2q \\
\dot{q} &= p.
\end{align*}$$
So if we put 
$$
r = \begin{pmatrix}p \\ q\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
\Omega = \begin{pmatrix}
2\lambda & \omega_0^2 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then the equation is written by $\dot{r} = -\Omega r$. The solution of this equation is simply $r(t) = e^{-\Omega(t - t_0)}r(t_0)$.

In some sense, we already solved the problem completely.
Usually, more explicit solution is, however, more desirable.
Since the characteristic equation $\det(\omega I - \Omega) = 0$ gives two roots $\omega_\pm = -\lambda \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2 - \omega_0^2}$, we have to consider if these two coincide or not.

In case $\omega_+ \neq \omega_-$, there exists a non-singular matrix $P$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
r(t) = e^{-P^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_+ & \\
 & \omega_- \end{pmatrix}
P(t - t_0)}r(t_0)
=
P^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-\omega_{+}(t - t_0)} & \\
 & e^{-\omega_{-}(t - t_0)} \end{pmatrix}
P\,r(t_0)
\end{align*}$$
To get a meaningful solution, one have to take real part of it if necessary ($\lambda < \omega_0$).

In case $\omega_+ = \omega_-$, the matrix $\Omega$ is not daiagonalizable and the calculation might become messy, but the basic story is the same as before.